# What is the difference between \ and \\ in file path

Tags: windows, web-config, directory, filepath

What is the difference between single slash and double slash in file path for Windows operating system such as

```
c:\\Personal\MyFolder\\MyFile.jpg
```

and

```
c:\Personal\MyFolder\MyFile.jpg
```

What if I use the single or double slash because I have tried both for storing images in my code (in webconfig file) and both of them work fine.

Is there any difference??

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Windows ignores double backslashes. So while the second syntax with `\` is correct and you should use that one, the first with `\\` works too.

The only exception is double-backslash at the very beginning of a path that indicates a UNC path.
See [Universal Naming Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention).

---

Though note that in many programming languages like C, C++, Java, C#, Python, PHP, Perl, a backslash works as an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Escape_sequences) in [string literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal). As such, it needs to be escaped itself (usually with another backslash). So in these languages, you usually need to use a double backslash in the string literal to actually get a single backslash for a path. So for example in C#, the following string literal is actually interpreted as `C:\Personal\MyFolder\MyFile.jpg`:

```cs
var path = "C:\\Personal\\MyFolder\\MyFile.jpg";
```

Though there are [alternative syntaxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Raw_strings). For example in C#, you can use the following syntax with the same result:

```cs
var path = @"C:\Personal\MyFolder\MyFile.jpg";
```