# (OpenCV , cv2) The cv2.error while capture the image through camera lens

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, raspberry-pi4

[Error (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 occurred when attempting to display an image using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572387/error-215-size-width0-size-height0-occurred-when-attempting-to-display-a)

I have the similar issue with this discussion, after I read it still don't have clue for how to address mine,that I post my case here

*I use raspberrypi 4 ; 32 bit, linux run python ;  logitech USB camera lens ; run in virtual environment*

- the python script `opencv_camera.py`

```
import cv2
 
# define a video capture object
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(1) ########## 1- device id =1###if 1 deosn't work try 2
 
while(True):
     
    ret, frame = vid.read()
 

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
     
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
 
vid.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

error occur:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) .... in function 'imshow'

- the output:

```
(venv) joy@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python opencv_camera.py
[ WARN:0@0.020] global /tmp/pip-wheel-u79916uk/opencv-python_ea2489746b3a43bfb3f2b5331b7ab47a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (902) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): can't open camera by index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joy/Desktop/opencv_camera.py", line 14, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /tmp/pip-wheel-u79916uk/opencv-python_ea2489746b3a43bfb3f2b5331b7ab47a/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:967: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

---

- troubleshooting status: now find out ret is none

```
import cv2
 
 
# define a video capture object
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(2) ########## 1- device id =1###if 1 deosn't work try 2
 
while(True):
    ret, frame = vid.read()
           

    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
               
    else:
       
        print("ret is empty")
        break

 
# After the loop release the cap object
vid.release()
# Destroy all the windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

output:

```
(venv) joy@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python opencv_camera.py
[ WARN:0@0.019] global /tmp/pip-wheel-u79916uk/opencv-python_ea2489746b3a43bfb3f2b5331b7ab47a/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (902) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video2): can't open camera by index
ret is empty
```

Comment: The image is most likely empty. You should check if the video capture is working by checking if `ret=True`.

Comment: Zero mean one camera, 1 mean 2 cameras and so on.

Comment: @toyota Supra,  Hi where is ur example zero amd one ? In `vid = cv2.VideoCapture(1)`

Comment: cv2.VideoCapture(0)  one camera. cv2.VideoCapture(1)  2 cameras and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take a Image, you should not use

```
while(True):
```

Because it means that you will be constantly reading what was from the camera.

Refer below for the code if you want to just take a picture, you may constantly run

```
ret, frame = vid.read()
```

to retake a new picture

CODE:

```
import cv2
 
 
# define a video capture object
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

#Read the current camera
ret, frame = vid.read()
cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
cv2.waitKey(1)
             
#Unattach the camera
vid.release()
# Destroy all the windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

after I changed `vid = cv2.VideoCapture()` to `0` now as video function is working, but my original purpose is taking one image though

```
import cv2
 
 
# define a video capture object
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0) ########## 1- device id =1###if 1 deosn't work try 2


 
while(True):
    ret, frame = vid.read()
             

    if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
       
           
    else:
       
        print("ret is empty")
        break
 
# After the loop release the cap object
vid.release()
# Destroy all the windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

- also for taking pic

```
import cv2
import time
 
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # video capture source camera (Here webcam of laptop)
ret,frame = cap.read() # return a single frame in variable `frame`
 
# run 60 sec x 2 min
time_end = time.time() + 100
 
while time.time() < time_end:
 
    while(True):
        cv2.imshow('img1',frame) #display the captured image
        if cv2.waitKey(60) & 0xFF == ord('y'): #save on pressing 'y'
            cv2.imwrite('/home/joy/Desktop/pic.png',frame)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
   
    cap.release()
    break
```