# How to get path to virtualenv in Windows?

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, visual-studio-code

First of all, i'm using bash in windows.
I'm trying to write the correct paths to my virtualenv in VSCode but I must be doing something wrong 
Any help will be really appreciated! thank you guys!

```
"python.pythonPath": "C\\Users\\Angel\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\\LocalState\\rootfs\\home\\aquesada\\.local\\share\\virtualenvs\\videoclub_django_new-coDPKRdg\\bin\\python",
"python.linting.pylintPath": "C\\Users\\Angel\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\\LocalState\\rootfs\\home\\aquesada\\.local\\share\\virtualenvs\\videoclub_django_new-coDPKRdg\\bin\\pylint",
"python.venvPath": "C:\\Users\\Angel\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\\LocalState\\rootfs\\home\\aquesada\\.local\\share\\virtualenvs"
```

Comment: Your `pythonPath` and `pylintPath` need `C:\\` at the start

Comment: you're right! thank you! but still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

**virtual env as environmental variable**

A virtual environment will set an environmental variable.

In Windows, you should be able to view that variable via `echo %VIRTUAL_ENV%`

In your Python code, you can grab that env var via `os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']`

**VS Code config**

`python.venvPath` should work. A few more things for you to try:

- adjust path formatting: a single backslash as delimiter should work; AFAIK Windows only requires [two consecutive backslashes at the start of the path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15969841/6813490)
- restart VS Code after updating configuration
- use the Command Palette to select the Python interpreter from your virtual environment

Comment: Thank you Zach! but I still don't know what I can do with that

Comment: Gotcha. I misinterpreted your question; I thought you were trying to use the path to the virtual env to do something in your Python code.

Comment: what should i write in my path?

Comment: updated for more info about adjustment you can make to your path string

Comment: Not working, there must be something i'm missing. Thank you anyway Zach