# Read a file in R without changing the working directory

Tags: r, read.csv, working-directory, setwd

How can others who run my R program read a file(eg: csv) used in my R code without having to change the working directory in setwd()?

Comment: Where does the data come from? If you want to find files relative to your R script, maybe look at the [here package](https://here.r-lib.org/). Or are you using RStudio? If so, consider using RStudio projects. Read more about [project oriented workflows](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/)

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you use the `here()` function in the `here` package in your code like this:

```
library(here)
Data1 <- read_csv(here("test_data.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`read.csv` has a `file` argument and if I were to quote from the inbuilt `R` help about `file`:

> If it does not contain an absolute path, the file name is relative to
> the current working directory, `getwd()`.

So, providing the absolute path of the file inside the `file` argument solves this problem.

---

### In Windows

Suppose your file name is `test.csv` and it's located in `D:\files\test_folder` (you can get the location of any file from its properties in Windows)

For reading this file you run:

```
df<-read.csv('D:\\files\\test_folder\\test.csv')
```

or

```
df<-read.csv('D:/files/test_folder/test.csv')
```

Suggested reading: [Why `\\` instead of `\`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15969841/8484779) and [Paths in programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Paths_in_programming_languages)

Haven't used `R` in Linux but maybe [Getting a file path in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5265702/8484779) might help

---

### Read from web

Just type in the web address of the dataset in the `file` attribute. Try:

```
df<-read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AdiPersonalWorks/Random/master/student_scores%20-%20student_scores.csv')
```

**Note:** This link contains a list of 25 students with their study hours and marks. I myself used this dataset for one of my earlier tasks and its perfectly safe